# How to retrieve "certain cell" data from an Excel xlsx file in a small Visual Studio C++ GUI desktop app I designed w/ dropdown, input & output fields

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, io, visual-studio-2022, xlsx

I have a task to solve. I'm not a programmer, but I've been playing around trying to learn. That being said, I really could use some help/guidance. I have an idea for a program to help me and my coworkers speed up our jobs. So I created a 2022 Visual Studio C++ (.NET Framework) GUI desktop application. Well, created the GUI part anyway. I made up a small app with a drop-down menu with choices, an input field associated with that dropdown choice and a few return data fields.

Basically, I need the program to find what a user inputs, from an excel xlsx sheet and returns specific data from cells pertaining to that request. The xlsx sheet has many columns and rows but the data needed is only in a couple of columns. So, depending on what the user asks for, the program will pull the data from multiple columns/rows.

Each row of the xlsx sheet contains many columns of data for a single item, example:
One row has 30 columns of different pieces of data but we only need a couple to be found and displayed.

It sounds like a simple task but I'm sure there is a lot of coding to do to accomplish this goal.

Any help and or guidance would be greatly appreciated. See screenshot of what I created.

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgtZf.jpg)

I’m a Graphic Designer so I can be of assistance in any Graphical needs anyone may have for their programs, icons, logos, etc.!

Thank you

Did much research but unsuccessful.

So the user will choose an option from the dropdown menu, type in the actual number coinciding with their choice and click search. All the fields at the bottom half should be filled in with data returned from the Excel xlsx sheet.